# Ubuntu Logs out immediately after logging in

Tags: login, lightdm

The problem began after installing the nvidia cuda toolkit and typing the command

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

I have tried several solutions from the ctrl-alt-f1 menu which did not work, listed below.
Soln 1)

```
sudo rm -v .Xauthority
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Soln 2)

```
sudo chown -R alex:alex /home/alex
```

Soln 3)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Soln 4)

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/old.Xauthority
logout
```

Soln 5)

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm --reinstall
```

Soln 6)

```
sudo chown -R $alex:$alex $HOME
```

Soln 7)

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the permission for the file: `~/.Xauthority`?